# How to set margin for index 0 of listView

Tags: android

I have a proper list view which has an adapter that extends BaseAdapter. 
Everything works fine, but I need a margin of 30 dp for index 0. How to achieve this?

I tried the below 2 code but it crashes.

```
View subView = createButtonView((MenuButton) getItem(position));
        if(position==0){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)subView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 0);
            subView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        return subView;





public View getSubView(int position){
        View subView = createButtonView((MenuButton) getItem(position));
        if(position==0){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            subView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        return subView;
    }
```

Also I cannot use a headerView because the child view might not always be a same view, its will be dynamic.

Comment: you mean 30dp margin for first row ?

Comment: Yes only for 1st row. If It was for every rows I can do it from the layout xml only right? But here I need only for the 1st row. Also I cannot give margin for the list because when I scroll then than portion will be clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple alternative is use
SpaceView with 30dp width in xml( space view is very light view in android)
and adjust the visiblity for positions

```
if (position == 0)
            yourxmlSpaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            yourxmlSpaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

for 30dp you can use this method to convert int to pixels

```
public int dpToPx(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics();
        int px = Math.round(dp
                * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
        return px;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the code. But the basic code I have mentioned above is crashing

Comment: Looks like a good idea, but space required api level 14. mine is 8

Comment: Then use textview or View or some other view

Comment: but one more problem, now when I select the row 0 the spaceview also gets selected. Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: write selector for the layout other than spaceview

wrap the other layout in container and assign background as default selector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61867/discussion-between-geo-paul-and-shashidhar-manchukonda).

Answer (score 0):

your listview can add a view to fake space with height is 30dp.

View:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/fake_view"
/>
```

adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent){
     ....
     View fakeView = v.findViewById(R.id.fake_view);
     fakeView.setVisibility(position == 1? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE)
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter class check for position zero and specify your layout parameters inside that if clause and add it to the convertView

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_main, convertView, false);
    }
    if(position == 0){

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)subView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 0);
        convertView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
      }

    return view;
}
```